Excel - Dependent Data Validation from multiple tables
EDITED:
I have a table from which column "A" is the "main choice" and Columns "D" and G" are dependent choices. However multiple choices from Column "A" will go to either D or G.
e.g. options "A" or "B" will allow selections from Column "D", options "C" - "F" allows selections from Column "G".
I can get this to work on a 1-1 scale (where option A = Column D and option B = Column G), but I can't figure out a x-1 method.
I tried an IFS statement, but that's too specific as the values might change, and Vlookup doesn't seem to quite work either.
I have named ranges for everything relevant (columns as well as selection choices that relate to the dependent choices for the vlookup)
I've been using this source as an example, but it's not quite the right concept.
https://www.contextures.com/exceldatavaldependindextables.html

There should not be a need to separate the dependent lists into Table2 and Table3. You may need these tables for some other purpose, but for the purpose of dependent data validation, keep everything in one list.  I'm not sure which aspect of this you are struggling with. Your question is not clear. Please edit it and provide more detail about what you have tried.

You edit did not clarify very much in what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried. Can you provide more context as to what exactly is happening in Col D & G, and what selections are meant to do what to each? Right now all i can gather is the user puts something into Col A and depending on that value something else happens in D or G, not much we can do with that information that will help you.
